# Guest can't submit answer Adaptative Card on Microsoft Teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm having an error with a custom bot when I send an adaptative card to a meeting and a guest tries to submit an answer. It works when a logged user tries to submit it. It used to work perfectly with a Guest. It seems like the problem is something about the bot login process.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '*BotId*' of undefined
at t.recordBotMriUsage (3.2-app.min-2477809.js:4)
at _.debounce.trailing (3.2-app.min-2477809.js:3)
at e (2-vendor.min-9ae85bb.js:64)
at f (2-vendor.min-9ae85bb.js:65)
at t.e.buttonClicked (3.2-app.min-2477809.js:3)
at o (lazy-ng1-mod-adaptive-card-components.min-1b02b78.js:1)
at c (lazy-ng1-mod-adaptive-card-components.min-1b02b78.js:1)
at t.handleOnExecuteAction (lazy-ng1-mod-adaptive-card-components.min-1b02b78.js:1)
at adaptiveCard.onExecuteAction (lazy-ng1-mod-adaptive-card-components.min-1b02b78.js:1)
at p (3.2-app.min-2477809.js:3)

Failed to get app entitlement for botId 28:*BotId*

500 Invoke failed due to internal error: Invoke failed: something went wrong in ProcessInvoke

[BotCardService::onButtonClicked_messageback()] sendInvoke failed: {"statusCode":500,"headers":{"cache-control":"no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache","content-length":"119","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","contextid":"tcid=******,server=*****,cv=*******/hfA.1.0","pragma":"no-cache","set-registrationtoken":"**redacted**"},"errorMessage":"Error Code: 500 ","errorCode":500,"request":{}}
```

[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJURp.png)

EDIT: Here is the manifest.json of the app

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.7/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.7",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "id": "redacted",
  "packageName": "redacted",
  "developer": {
    "name": "redacted",
    "websiteUrl": "redacted",
    "privacyUrl": "redacted",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "redacted"
  },
  "icons": {
    "color": "color.png",
    "outline": "outline.png"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "redacted",
    "full": "redacted"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "redacted",
    "full": "redacted"
  },
  "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
  "bots": [
    {
      "botId": "redacted",
      "scopes": ["personal", "groupchat"],
      "supportsFiles": false,
      "isNotificationOnly": false
    }
  ],
  "composeExtensions": [
    {
      "botId": "redacted",
      "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
      "commands": [
        {
          "id": "getPollCM",
          "type": "action",
          "title": "Generar encuesta prestador",
          "description": "Genera una encuesta para prestadores",
          "initialRun": true,
          "fetchTask": false,
          "context": ["commandBox", "compose"],
          "parameters": [
            {
              "name": "NIT",
              "title": "NIT del prestador",
              "description": "Solo números",
              "inputType": "text"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": ["identity", "messageTeamMembers"],
  "validDomains": ["redacted"]
}
```

Comment: Can you check your `manifest.json` file for me and verify that you are passing the "validDomains" property. Reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema#validdomains) for information on it. At first glance, I suspect that this is the issue.

Comment: Hi @StevenKanberg , the `manifest.json` has the "validDomains" poperty, I created it with Teams App Studio, it is empty thought. I don't access any external API on the card nor the whole app, only the bot `api/messagess` endpoint.

Comment: Could you edit your post to include your `manifest.json` file (replace any bot id's with generic text)? Also, when you say it used to work, what do you mean by that? Was that recently or awhile ago, using a previous version of the SDK, or something else?

Comment: I'd also be curious to see the adaptive card and the code for how you are sending it (editing your post again).

Comment: Can you please share your manifest.

Comment: Hi @StevenKanberg the adaptive card displays a simple survey, and I used the `OnTeamsMessagingExtensionSubmitActionAsync` and `OnTeamsMessagingExtensionBotMessagePreviewSendAsync` to send it. It is delivered and displayed correctly on the chat, a logged user on the same chat can submit it correctly but a guest cannot. It stopped working for guests around 2-3 weeks ago, no deliberately changes that I remember.

Comment: We are able to reproduced the issue and raised a bug for this.

Comment: I tested it again today and got this response from the RichText/Media_Card submit `invoke` request `{"errorCode":209,"message":"Validation failed for the invoke initiator or recipient."}`. Also the `chatentitlements` request responded this `{"errorCode":"AnonymousUsersInteractionNotSupported"}`. Does it mean that Guests will not be able to interact with bots/message extensions? Or maybe there is some configuration that I must enable?